# CMake, forward declarations, signals and 'No such file or directory'

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, include

I am trying to develop a user interface in Qt, which is  connected to some logic. I have successfully sent signals from the logic to the user interface, but now I require to do it the other way around too. I face a `QMainWindow: No such file or directory` error when I try to compile the project.

I know for sure that it is a problem of including the classes to each other, and therefore I have tried to perform some forward declaration. But I have been unable to do it properly. I have tried many ways but I don't seem to achieve it.

I tried to create an empty class in the client's header file, `class QTGUI;` and include the `qtgui.hpp` only in `client.cpp`, and the same analogous thing with `QTGUI` files. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

---

### Updated CMakeLists and source codes. The original stuff is below.

**Main CMakeLists**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(backendCode)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

SET(THREADLIBS "-lpthread -lboost_thread")

SET(FSLIBS "-lboost_filesystem -lboost_system")

add_subdirectory(gui)
add_subdirectory(server)
```

**GUI CMakeLists**: In comparison with the original code, I included the client stuff here.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(QtGui)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Network REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS})


add_executable(main main.cpp qtgui.cpp ../common/inotify.cpp 
../client/client.cpp ../common/message.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Network ${Boost_LIBRARIES} 
${THREADLIBS})
```

**QTGUI.h**

```
#ifndef QTGUI_H
#define QTGUI_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileSystemWatcher>

#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

#include "../common/inotify.hpp"

class Client;

namespace Ui {
class QTGUI;
}

class QTGUI : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
...
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<Client> client_;
    Ui::QTGUI* ui;
};
#endif // QTGUI_H
```

**QTGUI.cpp**

```
#include "QTGUI.h"
#include "ui_qtgui.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <QHostAddress>
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QIntValidator>
#include <QFileDialog>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include "../client/client.hpp"
...
```

**CLIENT.HPP**

```
#ifndef CLIENT_HPP
#define CLIENT_HPP

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

#include "../common/message.hpp"

class QTGUI;

class Client : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Client>
{
    {
        public:
        ...
        private:
        boost::shared_ptr<QTGUI> ui_;
        };

        #endif // CLIENT_H
```

**CLIENT.CPP**

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <cstdio> /* sprintf */

#include "client.hpp"
#include "../gui/QTGUI.h"

#include <unistd.h>

Client::Client():
...
```

---

### Original code

I have the following in my **main** CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(backendCode)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

SET(BOOSTHREAD "-lpthread -lboost_thread")

SET(FSLIBS "-lboost_filesystem -lboost_system")

add_subdirectory(gui)
add_subdirectory(client)
add_subdirectory(server)
```

The following, in the **gui** CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(QtGUI)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Network REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS})


add_executable(main main.cpp qtgui.cpp ../common/inotify.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main client Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Network ${Boost_LIBRARIES} 
${BOOSTHREAD})
```

In the qtgui.h header file I have the following code:

```
#ifndef QTGUI_H
#define QTGUI_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

#include "../client/client.hpp"

namespace Ui {
class QTGUI;
}
class QTGUI    : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
    private:
        boost::shared_ptr<Client> client_;
};
#endif
```

Finally, in the client.hpp file I have the following code:

```
#ifndef CLIENT_HPP
#define CLIENT_HPP

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

#include "../gui/qtgui.h"

class QTGUI;

class Client : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Client>
{
    ...
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<QTGUI> ui_;
};
#endif
```

---

**EDIT:** Added the `namespace` thing into the `qtgui.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client code, compiled without Qt support, includes a file that includes a Qt header. This won't ever work. The `#include "../gui/qtgui.h"` line in `client.hpp` is the source of the problem.

The forward declaration in `client.hpp` would be pointless since you've already included the `qtgui.h`. Choose one or the other. Most likely, you *do not* want to include `qtgui.h` in `client.hpp`. That should solve your problem.

Comment: If I don't include qtgui.h then I go back to the start point. However, if I leave the class QTGUI; in the client.hpp then when compiling I get an ui was not declared on this scope error. Could it be because of the namespace Ui of the qtgui.h file? PS: Sorry I did not include that in the original question. It has been updated.

Comment: @StrikeTeam You don't need to include it. I don't know what you mean by square one. It's supposed to work. Your code works for me if I follow the answer.

Comment: Let me explain myself better: if I leave the `class QTGUI;` inside the `client.hpp` file, in order to have it declared to use its signal functions, then the compiler complaints about `error: 'ui' was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: Okey solved. I firstly followed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868916/qt-c-yet-another-issue-about-accessing-ui-files) and then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466055/field-has-incomplete-type-error), and it seems to compile. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: @StrikeTeam Show the full source that reproduces the issue. Otherwise we'll be going in circles. At the moment, your design is broken. You can't use a class that uses Qt APIs in its interface (public or private doesn't matter) from a module that doesn't know anything about Qt. If you insist on using Qt in that class, put it into a [PIMPL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25250171/1329652). Nothing Qt-related must appear in that class's header!

Comment: On the one hand, I have the Qt class QTGUI which has some slots for the signals that the CLIENT sends. Now, I want to be able to make the QTGUI send some signals to the CLIENT slots. That is why, I need somehow to access the GUI from the client in order to use the GUI's signals. However I made it compile. Should I still post the entire source code?

Comment: According to your cmakelists, the client is not using Qt?! Or at least you don't show that.

Comment: Finally, I solved thanks to the PIMPL pattern, as you pointed out earlier. There was no other way of making it work. Thank you again for all your help.