# how to link a textbox made in QT designer with a coded function using signal slots

Tags: qt, textbox, io, qt-designer

I have made the ui using QT designer. Which has a textbox in main window in which user enters his name. **i want to call function 'input' when the data entered by user is over.**
but i cant find a way to link a textbox from ui designed using QT designer to a coded function form other class. 
I guess signal and slots (in qt designer) can only link to components of the same window.

Again,
**at the same time i want to store the name entered by the user in a char variable usr_nm[]** in the same function input. I later want to display the name in a text browser with some other details in function output.(-->Input and output function are in same class.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to define this in Qt Designer?

It seems to me it would be better if you simply used an auto-connection slot, for example:

```
on_textBoxName_textChanged()  // I'm assuming you are using QTextEdit
{
     ui->textBoxName->toPlainText();  // this returns text in QTextEdit as QString.  
}
```

This uses auto-connection - see [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect).

Comment: where should i write this? also isn't there a method to do that directly from qt designer.

Comment: This should be added to the *.hpp and *.cpp files associated with the *.ui file. Qt-designer allows you only to connect existing signals and slots, and since you want to do more, I don't see a way to do it in designer. (Qt4 designer doesn't support custom slots, as answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-create-a-custom-slot-in-qt4-designer) )